# Call 2 function in onPress ( navigation and submit form)

Tags: javascript, react-native

i made a form with the API react-hook-form and i would like to make another call when I click in the submit (i have already a function which get the data from the form). I use react navigation 5.0.5 for page changes but when i do the 2 actions it's not longer possible. I would like to know if you do have ideas for make multiple calls, I already tried to build a fonction with the different functions but nothing is called when I call this new function.

here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, ActivityIndicator,Image,TouchableOpacity,Icon } from 'react-native'
import Form from "./Form";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";




function Filtrage({ navigation }) {
  const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));


  return (
    <View style={styles.main_container}>
      <Text style={styles.titreHome} >Vos études ?</Text>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
          <TextInput
            style={styles.testField}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
            value={value}   
          />
        )}
        name="etudes"
        rules={{ required: true }}
        defaultValue=""
      />



  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bouton} >
      <Button color="white" title="Voir les fiches disponible" onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
      
  </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and the function I would like in the submit Button:

`onPress={() => navigation.navigate("listeCours")}`

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a lambda

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.bouton} >
      <Button color="white" title="Voir les fiches disponible" onPress={() => {
        handleSubmit(onSubmit)
        navigation.navigate("listeCours")
       }
      } />
      
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried this and only ```navigation.navigate("listeCours")``` works, on the other hand, the second function dont works and no errors are returned

Comment: No, this answer will not work. I hava same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this;

```
 onPress={() => {
     handleSubmit(onSubmit)() // <-- don't forget add additional '()'
     handleNewFunction()
 }}
```